# VsCode not giving syntax error on type casting

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

```ts
interface TypeA {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}
const b = <TypeA> { prop1: 'str', prop3: 'str' };
console.log(b.prop1);
```

vscode not giving syntax error on this case. I want "prop2 is missing" error

Comment: I am using Typescript

Comment: Hi, your example works (or doesn't work ;) just fine in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&ssl=5&ssc=11&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMicplAPaYCMAXMgM5hSgDmA3MaeVQEz1MWIDoQC+hQggogmyAEbIAvMgA8GbDgB8BMpRr0A5IIMAaXVQDMh48lGcpMigBsIAOicVWACjmueNAEp2IA). Could you prepare a playground example that shows the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the type on the variable name. Then you have what you want.

```ts
interface TypeA {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}
const b: TypeA = { prop1: 'str', prop3: 'str' };
console.log(b.prop1);
```

Comment: thank you. But declaring "b" is sample. Actually I want to pass it to function it's parameter is TypeA.

Comment: @БаярмагнайБалдангомбо Then why don't you set a type for the parameter of the function?